# Фильтрация по нескольким совпадениям

Tags: django, django-orm

Пусть у меня есть модель Django с 10 полями, на входе 10 значений. Как получить `QuerySet`, при выполнении которого из таблицы будет получены строки, в которых хотя бы `n` колонок совпадает (`n`<10)?

Answer (score 1):

Плохая архитектура, вынуждающуя к костылям. Лучше её изменить. Единственное решение, которое я вижу, при такой модели - использование пелёнки из [Conditional Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/conditional-expressions/):

```
SomeModel.objects.annotate(
    match_count=Case(When(bool_field1=value1, then=1), default=0, output_field=IntegerField()) +
    Case(When(bool_field2=value2, then=1), default=0, output_field=IntegerField()) +
    Case(When(bool_field3=value3, then=1), default=0, output_field=IntegerField()) +
    ...
).filter(match_count__gte=5)
```

Comment: Возможно вы тогда подскажите, как лучше спроектировать в данном случае? Мне нужно хранить матрицу `n` на `m`, в которой будут лежать значения типа `bool`. И при необходимости быстро отфильтровывать сущности, у которых эта матрица совпадает с входяшей матрицей больше, чем в `k` позициях

Comment: Самый подходящий вариант для хранения данных - это [ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield): `matrix = ArrayField(ArrayField(models.BooleanField()))`. А вот ваш поиск - это задача не для ORM. Я бы лучше переложил это на БД, написал хранимую процедуру, возвращающую идентификаторы подходящих записей.

Comment: вот [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41134260/django-jsonfield-inside-arrayfield) пишут, что искать по массиву плохо, а по двумерному тем более и что если проектирование дошло до этого, то нужно нормализовать данные. Я в итоге решил хранить матрицу, как бинарный вектор и при необходимости сортировать через И (вес a & b >= k)

Comment: Или так. И фильтрация ORM'ом проще будет. Но в плане структуры данных - это overkill, на мой взгляд.

Comment: В каком плане через ORM будет проще? Я делаю `raw()` запрос вот такой `SELECT * FROM MyModel WHERE (SELECT length(replace(x::TEXT, '0', '')) FROM ( VALUES (column_name::bit(56) & '00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000001') ) AS something(x)) >= k;` это как-то можно сделать без `RawQuerySet`?

Comment: Я про _Consider using a separate table with a row for each item that would be an array element._ В вашем случае всё-таки лучше SQL'ем.